# How to read Xml stored as blob in mysql via SQL into a readable string?

Tags: mysql

We have stored an XML file in the database as blob field. Now we would like to see the data in the SQL editor.

SELECT CAST(response AS CHAR(10000)) FROM response_table

we see the column as ???

Could someone help me on how to get the values in the readable format?

Thanks.

Comment: Which editor you are using ? You can use Toad for MySql.

Comment: i used Toad but it has only UTF-8, UTF-16 but i suspect the code is saving in other charset or format...please let me know how to view the data properly

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your editor to show the blob response. I use Toad for mySql. Which shows the response and I can view it in different formats like HEX, ASC11 etc. Your query will remain same, not casting is needed.

```
SELECT response FROM response_table
```

Comment: i tried but it shows junk character..for utf-8..how to confirm whether the data has been saved with ISO-8591-1 standard

Comment: Click on ASCII view, there are tabs.

Comment: Remember when the same object has been translated in java via hibernate and assigned to the appropriate object it shows the swedish character...